# Is there a way to require host to hold the intermediate CA in trust store and not rely solely on root ca

Tags: x509

I'm looking for a solution for the following case:

- We have PKI with root certificate distributed and trusted by all devices in the network.
- Unique intermediate CA distributed to every device for proxy MitM service.
- Limit the ability of a user to take its cert to impersonate sites to other users... the site will not get marked in the browser since the present root verifies it CA.

I'm curious if any cert policy can instruct the browser (for example) to require issuer cert present on the device and not only root CA.